# How can I change audio/webm to audio/wav (blob) in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I change audio/webm  to audio/wav?

```
onOutput(audio: any) {
    const file = new File([audio], 'audio.webm', { type: 'audio/webm' });
    this.sendFile(file);
}
```

I do something like this, but in the end I need to send not a .webm, but a .wav

Please tell me where to go!

Comment: Usually this task is performed on the backend. Do you want to perform this transformation on the browser of your user?

Comment: yes @JRichardsz, For example, discord or whatsapp web, don't they do it in the browser?

Comment: I'm not sure. Inspecting the discord web we could determine if the ajax returns .webm. With  a large file the browser could freeze.

Comment: @JRichardsz I'll go take a look

Comment: web whatsapp is using opus @JRichardsz

Comment: Do you mean this [opus](https://github.com/xiph/opus)? I think is a backend library based on c++ not for javascript :|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241021/discussion-between-jrichardsz-and-trr).